# Passing file from ajax to spring contorller

Tags: ajax, spring, file-upload

I have form in that, apart from other fields, there is file drop down and file browser button.  When the user uploads a file and clicks the button, an Ajax call is made and the file is submitted to the controller.  The Javascript shows the file, but in controller it's empty.

HTML:

```
<label for="selectEnclosure" style="margin-left:8%; ">Select an Enclosure:</label>
<select id="templateEnclosuresDropDown" class="validate[required] input_user" style="width:25%"  title="Select>Enclosure"</select>

<c:forEach items="${templateEnclosures}" var="templateDDEnclosure" varStatus="loopStatus">
    <c:if test="${templateEnclosure.enclosureType.name!='Default'}"> {
        <option value="${templateDDEnclosure.persistentId}"> ${templateDDEnclosure.enclosure.name} </option>
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
<option value="0">Additional Enclosure</option>
```

Ajax call:

```
userhome.upload = function() {
    alert(" pelae sai");
    var form=$('<form></form>');

    form.attr("method", "post");
    form.attr("action", SECURE_CONTEXT_PATH_ROOT + "/letter/melletter/uploadEnclosure")
    form.processData()

    var field =$('<input></input>');

    field.attr("enclosureFile", $('#enclosureFile').prop('files')[0]);
    field.attr("enclosurename" ,$('#templateEnclosuresDropDown :selected').text());
    field.attr("templateId",$("#codeNameId").val());

    var url = SECURE_CONTEXT_PATH_ROOT + '/letter/melletter/uploadEnclosure';

    $(document.body).append(form);
    form.submit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do would be adding this attribute to your form element:

```
enctype="multipart/form- data"
```